# How to get last selected radio button id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I have two UL lists with some radio buttons. Now I want to get last selected radio button `ID attribute` form their `UL`.

For example:

- If I selected radio button from first `UL` then return selected radio `ID`.
- If I selected radio button from second `UL` then return seledted radio `ID`.

I have tried bellow code but not working properly. If you try with selecting first radio button from first `UL` you will get alert with selected `ID`, but when you selected radio button from second `UL` you will get alert from first `UL` and that I dont want. :(

I want to get last checked radio button `ID` from that `UL`.

Any idea how to do this?

**Can you please check with this way:**

- First select 20 from first `UL` you will get 20.
- Second select 80 from second `UL` you will get 80.

Now again change radio button from first `UL` and that changed radio `ID` I want.

Here is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mananpatel/9v3ex2j0/1/).

Thanks.

```js
$("#update_cart").click(function() {
  var radioID = $("input[type='radio']:checked").attr("id");
  if (radioID) {
    alert(radioID);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="one">
  <li>
    <label for="1" class="label_check">
      <input type="radio" id="1" name="one" value="10">10
    </label>
  </li>

  <li>
    <label for="2" class="label_check">
      <input type="radio" id="2" name="one" value="20">20
    </label>
  </li>

  <li>
    <label for="3" class="label_check">
      <input type="radio" id="3" name="one" value="30">30
    </label>
  </li>

  <li>
    <label for="4" class="label_check">
      <input type="radio" id="4" name="one" value="40">40
    </label>
  </li>

  <li>
    <label for="5" class="label_check">
      <input type="radio" id="5" name="one" value="50">50
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul class="two">
  <li>
    <label for="6" class="label_check">
      <input type="radio" id="6" name="two" value="40">60
    </label>
  </li>

  <li>
    <label for="7" class="label_check">
      <input type="radio" id="7" name="two" value="70">70
    </label>
  </li>

  <li>
    <label for="8" class="label_check">
      <input type="radio" id="8" name="two" value="100">80
    </label>
  </li>

  <li>
    <label for="9" class="label_check">
      <input type="radio" id="9" name="two" value="120">90
    </label>
  </li>

  <li>
    <label for="10" class="label_check">
      <input type="radio" id="10" name="two" value="120">100
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>

<input type="button" id="update_cart" class="update_cart" value="Update Cart">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
$("#update_cart").click(function () {
  var radioID = $("input[type='radio'].active").attr("id");
  if (radioID) {
      alert(radioID);
  }
});

$("input[type='radio']").click(function(){
  $('.active').removeClass('active');
     $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

### Working Demo

Comment: Thanks for you help. Can you please check with this way: `1. First select 20 from first UL you will get 20`  `2. Second select 80 from second UL you will get 80.` Now again change radio button from first UL and that I want.

Comment: Do you want to uncheck radio button from first ul when radio from second is chosen??

Comment: No I dont want to uncheck redio button.